# Flutter hot relode not working with one perticular device

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i am using flutter for 2 months and have made some basic apps with it but now i am having issues with the Hot Relode function, it started hapning since i have changed the smartphone on which i used to test the apps.

i am currently using IQOO Z6 (Funtuch OS 13 based on Android version 13) as my phone

the flutter version i am developing with is 3.7.1

the error i am getting is:

√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly
Error launching application on I2127.
Exited (sigterm)

when i try to run it on a defferent device it works fine but it dose'nt work on the IQOO,
i reset my phone and reset my computer as well then reinstall everything again but the issue is the same, i do not know if this is a bug in the framework or in my device or i am dooing something wrong(Most likely).

Comment: Have you enabled developer options on your phone?

Comment: This may be unrelated, but 3.7.x is very new and has issues with Hot restart in Chrome, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119241. I'd first troubleshoot by downgrading Flutter.